# Marketing Cloud iOS MobilePush - Refresh Messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-ios, alert

We are using Marketing Cloud iOS SDK (v4.9.6) to implement MobilePush. We are using swift.

We are sending Alert + Inbox messages, and it works. However with some implications.

When sending Alert + Inbox, the Inbox message doesn't appear until the alert is clicked. Is it possible to make the inbox message appearing independent of the alert?

Also when sending only Inbox, the message doesn't appear until the the app is restarted. Refreshing the tableView datasource doesn't do the trick. I have seen that there is a method called *sfmc_refreshMessages* in the v5.0.0 SDK, is there something similar in v4.9.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not anything similar in v4.9.6 and `sfmc_refreshMessages` in v5.x can be used to resolve your problem, however, please open a Voice of Customer (VOC) request describing this issue so it can be discussed for a future change as it would be best, as you noted, for the message to be present when the notification is received.

Also, note, however that this is largely a testing concern as under "normal" user circumstances a user would have to be using your application at the moment the message was received in order for this to be an issue.  Any other situation where your application is *not* currently being used will result in the message being available immediately when the user opens the app, clicks the notification, etc.